# Flexbox bug on safari

Tags: html, css, flexbox, safari

I'm having an issue with some divs in Safari, other browsers work fine. Sometimes, but not every time, these rectangles appear, distort the layout, and overlap the images. It doesn't occur on my local server, just when I deploy it.

[Take note of the background color appearing over the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o94Ei.jpg)

It fixes itself if:

1. I resize/zoom the page.
2. I open web inspector (just open it, not anything else)
3. I refresh the page—sometimes

This is what I have for the three divs (.ldb-part) and their parent div (.ldb):

HTML:

```
        <div class="ldb">
        <div class="ldb-part">
            <h3>Landscape</h3>
            <img src="/Image1.jpg" alt="">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="ldb-part">
            <h3>Design</h3>
            <img src="/Image2.jpg" alt="">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="ldb-part">
            <h3>Build</h3>
            <img src="/Image3.jpg" alt="">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
        </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.ldb {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;

    justify-content: center;

    position: absolute;
    top: 93%;
    max-width: 70vw;
    height: 20em;
    padding-bottom: 4em;
}

.ldb-part {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;

    justify-content: space-around;

    flex-direction: column;

    text-align: center;

    width: 30%;
    height: inherit;
    margin: 0 1em;
    padding: .5em;
    border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #FFFDF8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience flexbox does not work in Safari at all, but it worked when I substituted it with gird display.

Using grid display may solve the problem here to

```
    .ldb-part {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;

    text-align: center;

    width: 30%;
    height: inherit;
    margin: 0 1em;
    padding: .5em;
    border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #FFFDF8;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just added the HTML. I may try to make the ldb-part divs into grids instead...

Comment: I replaced the image so my result is clearer. The .ldb div aligns itself fine on the page and it also aligns the .ldb-part divs inside it correctly. However, the .ldb-part divs mess up their child elements.

Comment: flexbox on parent element usually disrupt child positioning, but I think that one of these lines are causing the trouble:                                     
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;

Comment: Thank you again. I've tried your grid solution and even taking display off of .ldb-part entirely (along with its other properties align, justify, etc.) and I've managed to move the strange rectangle down from the images to the text. Still appears for me though.

Answer (score 0):

[This workaround for a separate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169089/weird-css-stretching-issue-in-ios7-safari-and-chrome) seems to be a bandaid solution for my issue.

Here's hoping it doesn't return...

Answer (score 0):

While Safari, a Webkit engine browser, claims support for display: flex, my discovery shows Webkit engine supports it partially, it sometimes overlays childs on each other. It's weird but old specification display: -webkit-box in this case works as expected.